# integrated terminal shows its text in black on MacOS Montrey

Tags: visual-studio-code

vscode version: 1.68.0
macos version: 12.4 (Montrey)

Steps to Reproduce:

- Launch VSCode
- View -> Terminal

This issue also occurs when all extensions are disabled.

Screen shots:

[image]

how can I solve this?

Comment: Open your VS Code settings.json file and search “integrated terminal” there you will find your palette settings and adjust them.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your terminal colors (and not only) in settings.json.

Open them via the command palette (Cmd + Shift + P on Mac) by typing `>Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

There, you can paste the following settings to configure all the colors you need (`terminal.foreground` would be your font color).

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.foreground": "#A89984",
    "terminal.background": "#1D2021",
    "terminalCursor.background": "#A89984",
    "terminalCursor.foreground": "#A89984",
    "terminal.ansiBlack": "#1D2021",
    "terminal.ansiBlue": "#0D6678",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlack": "#665C54",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlue": "#0D6678",
    "terminal.ansiBrightCyan": "#8BA59B",
    "terminal.ansiBrightGreen": "#95C085",
    "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta": "#8F4673",
    "terminal.ansiBrightRed": "#FB543F",
    "terminal.ansiBrightWhite": "#FDF4C1",
    "terminal.ansiBrightYellow": "#FAC03B",
    "terminal.ansiCyan": "#8BA59B",
    "terminal.ansiGreen": "#95C085",
    "terminal.ansiMagenta": "#8F4673",
    "terminal.ansiRed": "#FB543F",
    "terminal.ansiWhite": "#A89984",
    "terminal.ansiYellow": "#FAC03B"
}
```

Comment: I've done it, and it didn't work on the text color. Only background color changes!